# How to check if specific local git branch is up-to-date with the remote version?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am aware that many similar questions to this have been asked, however I feel there is a lot of ambiguity in a lot of the answers.

My situation:

1 repo called Bicycle which has 2 branches master and staging.

Assume that my local repo (master and staging) is up to date with the remote.

Then, another person working on the project creates a branch called day-5 and makes some changes to the project.

Said person, once done making his changes, pushes his changes, then merges the changes made on day-5 with the branch staging, but not master.

My question:

Assuming that I do not necessarily know that any changes have been made to staging. What is the most simple way for me to check if there have been changes made to the remote version of staging that my local version does not have?

Comment: It would, I think, help if you were to link to the other questions-and-answers that you found unhelpful, and described why they were unhelpful.  In any case CodeWizard's answer below appears to be correct for your setup.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the most simple way for me to check if there have been changes made to the remote version of staging that my local version does not have?

First of all you can execute a fetch

```
# update the local repository (no the branch just the repository)
git fetch --all --prune

# compare the local branch to the remote branch
git diff <branch> <origin/branch>

# if you are on the current branch you can drop the first part 
# git will use the current branch as the left branch
git diff <origin/branch>
```

There are few other command which will do teh same more or less

```
git log <branch> ^<origin/branch>
git log ^<branch> <origin/branch>
```

It will log the differences like in pull/push

Answer (score 0):

You should just do

```
git checkout staging
```

To  switch to that branch then

```
git status
```

Should tell you if you are up to date with remote or if your branch can be fastforwarded.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime if you are in a local branch and need to be updated with any branch in the remote you can try this

```
git pull origin <remote_branch_name>
```

In your case if you want your local branch to be updated with staging branch

```
git pull origin staging
```